# Classification of mapping tori

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

Assume $M$ is a topological space and $f\in \operatorname{Homeo}(M)$, then $f$ obviously plays a significant role in the torus bundle

$$M_f = M\times I/\{(x,0)\sim (f(x),1)\mid x\in M\}.$$

Hence there should be some general result of the following type: $M_f$ and $M_g$ are bundle isomorphic (resp. diffeomorphic) if and only if "W", where W is a relation between $f$ and $g$.

Can someone help give W and explain? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure "torus bundle" is right, I've heard "mapping torus" used for this construction.  Do you want your maps (between mapping tori or whatever) to necessarily preserve the I-coordinate, or at least take each M x {t_0} to some M x {t_1}?

Comment: @ Aaron Mazel-Gee.sorry,i made a mistake.as you point out,what i mean is mapping torus.

Comment: @Sara - It would be nice if you edited your question to fix the title. 

Comment: At least in 3-manifold topology, the term 'torus bundle' is usually used in the special case of this construction when M is a 2-torus.

Answer (score 8):

Your $M_f$ is usually called the "mapping torus" of $f$, as Aaron points out.  It comes with a map to the circle $S^1 = I/(0 \sim 1)$ and this map is a fibre bundle with fibres isomorphic to $M$.

First of all, the bundle isomorphism type of the bundle $M_f \to S^1$  only depends on the the isotopy class of $f$; i.e. if $f_0$ and $f_1$ are homotopic through homeomorphisms $f_t$ then $M_{f_0}$ and $M_{f_1}$ will be isomorphic bundles.  This reduces you to working with the mapping class group, which you probably already knew since I see the mapping-class-groups tag included.

Now, it's an easy exercise to check that $M_f$ and $M_g$ are isomorphic bundles if and only if $f$ and $g$ are conjugate in the mapping class group of $M$.

Comment: I wonder if there is a subtle point lurking here... if $f_0$ and $f_1$ are isotopic (homotopic through homeomorphisms) then the two bundles will be homeomorphic.  However, the question asked about diffeomorphism.  This is not my area, so I don't see that a diffeotopy (homotopic through diffeomorphisms?) gives a diffeomorphism of bundles... It feels like the "quality" of the derivative of the time direction will be important? 


Comment: For a diffeotopy it is exactly the same short argument;  topologically isotopic maps give homeomorphic bundles, and smoothly isotopic maps give diffeomorphic bundles.  And in fact, reducing to the mapping class group is unnecessary.  If f and g are isotopic then they are conjugate. 

Comment: For the second question (in brackets): if the bundles are just diffeomorphic and not bundle-isomorphic, then the mapping classes need not be conjugate. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241822/homeomorphic-but-non-conjugate-mapping-tori/241832#241832

Answer (score 5):

Mapping tori come equipped with a projection to the circle: $p\colon M_f\to S^1$. Bundle isomorphism is isomorphism of the total space that commutes with the projection. A weaker notion of isomorphism for mapping tori is an isomorphism that commutes with the projection only up to homotopy. [Pseudoisotopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoisotopy_theorem) is the name for the relation on isomorphisms of $M$ that replaces isotopy in this coarser notion of equivalence of mapping tori.

If $M$ is a simply connected manifold of high dimension, then pseudoisotopy implies isotopy and preserving the homotopy class of the map to the circle isn't a big deal, so isomorphism of mapping tori is pretty much isotopy of mapping classes. But if $M$ is not simply connected, there are two ways that mapping tori may be isomorphic without being bundle isomorphic: there may be more pseudoisotopies than isotopies and there may be isomorphisms that do not preserve the homotopy class of the map to the circle.

Comment: I'm not sure about the high-dimensional situation, but in two dimensions it's worth noting that pseudoisotopy and isotopy are the same (by a non-obvious theorem).

Comment: @DylanThurston Right, in 2d pseudoisotopy implies homotopy implies isotopy. In both low and high dimensions (but not smooth 4), the answer is that the difference between isotopy and pseudoisotopy is a higher Whitehead group, which should vanish for aspherical spaces (Borel conjecture). Waldhausen proved the pseudoisotopy=isotopy for Haken 3-manifolds, suggesting that the K-theory gadget vanishes. Hence his seemingly sharp turn into K-theory. (I imagine that for some 3d lens space pseudoisotopy is coarser than isotopy.)

Comment: @DylanThurston Actually, I was wrong. In high dimensions even if $Wh_2$ vanishes, as for free abelian groups, there is an additional obstruction for pretty much any space that is not simply connected. For the nicest spaces around, $S^n\times S^1$ and $(S^1)^n$, the group of homeomorphisms pseudo-isotopic to the identity but not isotopic is the $\mathbb Z/2$ vector space on the set of nontrivial conjugacy classes of elements in the fundamental group (or maybe the subspace invariant under inversion?). Same for diffeomorphisms.